# From which Android version provided Screen Capture?

Tags: android, version, screen-capture

we want to let users to capture screen shot on our app , but thinking that some  older version like 2.3 devices don't have Screen Capture function by default . So Screen Capture was provided since which version ? so that we can tell users about this .

Answer (score 1):

Screenshot support has been added to Android in version Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich).

Comment: Thank you :) . Seems some manufactories like Samsung already customize this function even on 2.2/2.3 , Any other manufactories have non-primitive Screen Capture in old version ?

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot capturing functionality was involved in the API 4.0 ICS which you can check into the [Features List](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0-highlights.html)

**If you don't have ICS or your phone doesn't have a built-in screenshot feature, you can try an Android app that does or doesn't require rooting your Android device.**

> Unfortunately, Android 2.3 and below doesn't have screenshotting built-in. However, some devices (like many Samsung phones) do have these features, but it varies from phone to phone. for example, on many Samsung phones, you can press the Home and Power buttons at the same time to take a screenshot. Google around to see if your own phone has a built-in shortcut.P
>
> If your phone doesn't have a shortcut built-in, you'll need to use an app like [No Root Screenshot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.edwardkim.android.screenshotitfullnoroot) it. You'll need to install it on your phone and install its free companion app on your computer, which will enable screenshots. You'll have to plug your phone back into your computer every time you reboot it, but you'll be able to take screenshots directly from your phone which is great.